# Filtering data in python pandas based on window of unique rows and boolean logic

Tags: python, pandas, data-transform

I would appreciate an elegant solution for filtering rows based on boolean conditions depending on unique identifiers.
My dataset is a kind of mixture of wide and long formats. There are about 100 variables, but three of them are in question for the example: `idkey`,  `method`, and `value`. In summary, there are multiple instances of rows with the same `idkey` but different `method` or `value`.

Example dataframe:

```
data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'idkey':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                         'method':['Sail', 'Sail', 'Run', 'Sail', 'Sail', 'Run', 'Sail', 'Sail', 'Walk'], 
                         'value':[1.2, 4.5, 3.4, 3.1, 4.5, 7.1, 2.5, 5.2, 1.7]})
```

I would like to have an elegant/pythonic solution for filtering based on

1. the rule that we drop rows where the method is "sail",
2. except if the individual also walks (then we keep the rows where the method is "sail").

I can imagine several not that elegant solutions, e.g.

1. one could make the table wide format, then apply the filter to the columns, and then make the table from wide to long again, and
2. I used the following in-elegant solution for filtering:

```
# General rule:
## All individuals except if method either "walk" or "sail"
data_rule=data.loc[(~data['method'].isin(['Walk', 'Sail'])), ]

# Exception rule:
## All individuals if method is "walk"
data_walk=data.loc[(data['method'].isin(['Walk'])), ]
## All individuals if method is 'sail' and method is 'walk'
data_sail=data.loc[data['method'].isin(['Sail']) &
                   data['idkey'].isin(data_walk['idkey']), ]
data_exception=pd.concat([data_walk, data_sail])

# Final table
data_filtered = pd.concat([data_rule, data_exception])
```

Could anybody suggest a more elegant solution without transforming the table from wide to long or splitting the data and then once again combining the data? In principle, it reminds me of a rolling function or window function or something, but lost my way to figuring the solution out. Though the example is simple, I would appreciate a solution that could be used when more complex boolean, etc. rules need to be applied.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is first identify the key ids that are exceptions (i.e., contains both 'Sail' and 'Walk'), then create a boolean mask for filtering using this.

```
out = data.groupby('idkey')['method'].apply(lambda x: {'Walk', 'Sail'}.issubset(x))
ignore_ids = out.index[out].values
```

`ignore_ids` contains all `keyids` that are exceptions and should be ignored when removing `method='Sail'`. Now create the mask and apply it:

```
drop_condition = (data['method'] == 'Sail') & ~data['idkey'].isin(ignore_ids)
data[~drop_condition]
```

Result:

```
  idkey  method  value
2     1     Run    3.4
5     2     Run    7.1
6     3    Sail    2.5
7     3    Sail    5.2
8     3    Walk    1.7
```